# How to try different targets in one grid-search

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, grid-search

say one regression problem using linear regression. I want to grid search different target y, to find out in which target model performs best.

Is any way to implement it in Sklearn?

---

for example,

Input:

- X, feature matrix
- Price, price array
- y, =price.diff(n).

I want to loop different n, and do regression between X and price.diff(n). Want to find out which estimator has the highest correlation.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to identify the correlation between the predictors and the response (dependent) variable. You can simply try the correlation matrix table.

```
df.corr()
```

If you want to plot this one, you can try generating a heat map to visualize the correlation strength against your y. The code below will return you a heat map to show the correlation strength.

```
# Plotting correlation matrix heat map
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

cor_df = df.corr()                         # correlation of all attributes in df
k = 3                                      # Total number of variables

# Sorting the columns by largest correlation against target variable
cols = cor_df.nlargest(k, "y")["y"]
cols_index = cols.index

# Setting figure & plotting
f, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (16,10))    # Size of the figure

sns.heatmap(df[cols_index].corr(), annot = True, linewidths = .5,
           cmap = "YlGnBu")
```

Last but not least, if you are trying to identify the best hyperparameters for your regression model. You may use either [`GridSearchCV()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) or [`RandomizedSearchCV()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.RandomizedSearchCV.html) from the `sklearn` library.

To do a `GridSearchCV()`, you will have to first define the range of hyperparameters you want to test in a dictionary and pass them in as a dictionary. Below is just an example since we don't have your dataset:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Recommended: Define hyperparameters you wish to test
params = {"normalize": [True, False], "fit_intercept": [True, False]}

# Generate base model & run GridSearchCV (Note that return_train_score lets you print the best parameters)
reg = LinearRegression()
optimal = GridSearchCV(reg, cv = 5, param_grid = params, scoring = "accuracy", return_train_score = True)

# Fit training data
optimal.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Print the best hyperparameters from your Grid Search
print(f"Best Parameters: {optimal.best_params_}")
```